# How to separate a record to get the amount

Tags: mysql, stock

I got total 160 Quantity in the Stock.

How to get first 100 quantity total amount and last 60 quantity total amount?

The table is sort by Date and Stock ID.

```
tblStock
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+ Stock ID + Product ID + Quantity + Amount   + Date       +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        1 +       1001 +       50 +    10.00 + 2014-11-10 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        2 +       1001 +       70 +    11.00 + 2014-11-11 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        3 +       1001 +       30 +     9.90 + 2014-11-12 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        4 +       1001 +       10 +    10.20 + 2014-11-13 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

I need two result of below. Thanks

```
Result A (first 100 quantity)
+------------+----------+--------------+
+ Product ID + Quantity + Total Amount +
+------------+----------+--------------+
+       1001 +      100 +      1050.00 +
+------------+----------+--------------+

Result B (last 60 quantity)
+------------+----------+--------------+
+ Product ID + Quantity + Total Amount +
+------------+----------+--------------+
+       1001 +       60 +       619.00 +
+------------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: did you want result as 100-19.90 and 60-20.20 ??

Comment: post a sample result

Comment: I want a result A = ((50 x 10) + (50 x 11)) , result B = ((20 x 10) + (30 x 9.90) + (10 x 10.20)), result A is first 100 quantity, result B is last 60 quantity. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For first 100

> select `Product ID`, sum(Quantity) as Quantity, sum(Amount) as `TotalAmount`
>   from (SELECT * from tblstock order by `tblStock`.`Stock ID`
>   ASC limit 100) t1 GROUP BY `Date`,`Product ID`

For last 60

> select `Product ID`, sum(Quantity) as Quantity, sum(Amount) as `Total
>   Amount` from (SELECT * from tblstock order by `tblStock`.`Stock ID`
>   DESC limit 60) t1 GROUP BY `Date`,`Product ID`

Comment: Sorry, this is no a result i want, my result request no a record limit, is a stock quantity limit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Result A:**

```
SELECT A.ProductID AS 'Product ID', '100' AS 'Quantity', SUM(A.Amount) as 'Total Amount'
FROM tblStock A
WHERE StockID IN (SELECT B.StockID from tblStock B ORDER BY B.StockID ASC LIMIT 100)
```

**Result B**:

```
SELECT A.ProductID AS 'Product ID', '60' AS 'Quantity', SUM(A.Amount) as 'Total Amount'
FROM tblStock A
WHERE StockID IN (SELECT B.StockID from tblStock B ORDER BY B.StockID DESC LIMIT 60)
```

Instead of using IN, you can use JOIN.

**Result A:**

```
SELECT A.ProductID AS 'Product ID', '100' AS 'Quantity', SUM(A.Amount) AS 'Total Amount'
FROM tblStock AS A
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT StockID from tblStock ORDER BY StockID ASC LIMIT 100) AS B
ON A.StockID = B.StockID
```

**Result B**:

```
SELECT A.ProductID AS 'Product ID', '60' AS 'Quantity', SUM(A.Amount) AS 'Total Amount'
FROM tblStock AS A
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT StockID from tblStock ORDER BY StockID DESC LIMIT 60) AS B
ON A.StockID = B.StockID
```

Comment: I got this error #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. Thank

Comment: Now that I have updated the query. Please give a try. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i tested already, but the result Total Amount output is 41.09. Thanks.