# limit results based on SUM of column

Tags: mysql

How to select range of record for Quantity.

```
tblStock
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+ Stock ID + Product ID + Quantity + Amount   + Date       +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        1 +       1001 +       50 +    10.00 + 2014-11-10 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        2 +       1001 +       70 +    11.00 + 2014-11-11 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        3 +       1001 +       30 +     9.90 + 2014-11-12 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        4 +       1001 +       10 +    10.20 + 2014-11-13 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Example i want get first 100 Quantity record. (Result A)

```
Result A
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+ Stock ID + Product ID + Quantity + Amount   + Date       +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        1 +       1001 +       50 +    10.00 + 2014-11-10 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        2 +       1001 +       50 +    11.00 + 2014-11-11 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Example i want get last 60 Quantity record. (Result B)

```
Result B
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+ Stock ID + Product ID + Quantity + Amount   + Date       +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        2 +       1001 +       20 +    11.00 + 2014-11-11 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        3 +       1001 +       30 +     9.90 + 2014-11-12 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
+        4 +       1001 +       10 +    10.20 + 2014-11-13 +
+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to separate a record to get the amount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162988/how-to-separate-a-record-to-get-the-amount)

Comment: if possible you should give link of `http://sqlfiddle.com/` with test data so that we can help you fast and correct and you can get answer fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change ASC and DESC in the ORDER BY clause accordingly.

Result A:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY StockID DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Result B:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY StockID ASC
LIMIT 60
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, this is no my request. I want list out sum is 100 in first (Result A) and sum is 60 at last (Result B). Thanks

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you to show me the expected output by editing your question?